# How Do I Add SSL/TLS Connection Security Option to Evolution Mail?

Tags: email, ssl, evolution

As the title indicates, I am having trouble moving one of my mail accounts from Thunderbird to Evolution Mail because the mail server where my email is located will only accept a SSL connection.  Thunderbird's 'SSL/TLS' default connection security option works perfectly, but Evolution Mail only provides 'STARTTLS after connecting' and 'TLS on a dedicated port' as connection security options.  Can someone dummy-proof instructions on how to get my Evolution mail to support SSL connections?

Ubuntu 18.04

Evolution 3.28.5

Can't find a single thing explaining why SSL support is NOT by default built into Evolution.  Even Evolution's own help docs say that SSL is supported, but the actual option for SSL connection simply is not there.

I uninstalled evolution, installed the PPA, and re-installed.  There is no option for SSL connection security... banging head on wall... now.

This is what I see:

[image]

[image]

**NOTE:** I have tried all three Security Encryption Methods, but none work.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

In a bit of "technical randomness" my problem seems to have sorted itself out, at least partially.

The correct settings should be "TLS on a dedicated port" for IMAP & SMTP.

There is thorough explanation of this posted in response to the same [question on askubunt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257324/how-do-i-add-ssl-tls-connection-security-option-to-evolution-mail)u by @Thoms Ward.

I have 2 mail accounts on the server that I am trying to connect to.  For the first account I put in the proper, aforementioned settings "TLS on a dedicated port", then after receiving connections, decided to just leave it alone and do other work.  I come back to hours later and apparently something updated itself on the mail server hosting my mail and suddenly my mail downloaded.

So then, I am all happy and giddie and decide to go ahead and put in the account settings for my 2nd account on the same server, but of course, I was answered with connection Error messages... So does everyone get. Two different email accounts on the same mail server, both using the same exact settings. One account works, one account does not...

bang head into wall now.

In any case, I plan to leave it as is and hope the mail server finally updates itself and allows me to download my mail so that I can complete my migration from thunderbird to evolution.